# not https or secure connection - ISP reads?

Tags: https

If you surf over Tor Browser and go on websites that are not https or secure, can your ISP see those sites?

If not, can people see those sites wirelessly, pcap wireshark etc?

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, the data would be seen from the exit node to the web server, but not to the ISP.

Wireshark and similiar programs could capture all Tor data, HTTP and HTTPS but this would only be used by the FBI or snoopy neighbors